Esimate of the Levi form of distance squared function
Let $(X,\omega)$ be a compact Kähler manifold. Let $\widetilde{X}$ be the universal cover of $X$. We denote by $\omega$ abusively  the pullback metric of $\omega$ on $\widetilde{X}$.  Fix a base point $z_0$ on $\widetilde{X}$ and we define a function $h(z)=d(z,z_0)^2$ on $\widetilde{X}$, where $d(-,-)$ is the distance function on $\widetilde{X}$ with respect to the metric $\omega$.
Question: for the hession $dd^c h$, can we prove that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for almost all points $z\in \widetilde{X}$, we have
$$
|dd^c h(z)|_\omega\leq C?
$$
